# Stuck on comparing answers

Tags: android

I am making a quiz app.I am stuck on comparing answers.I have added a dialog to show if the answer is right and it works well so does toast.but when I compare for wrong answer on each word I type I get toast wrong.what's the problem here is the code what I use to compare

```
boolean isCorrectAnswer() {
    String player_answer = "";
    //concat all letters from answer buttons in one string
    for (int i = 0; i < answer_line.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < answer_line[i].getChildCount(); j++) {

            Button b = (Button) answer_line[i].getChildAt(j);
            player_answer += b.getText().toString();

        }
      //compare player's answer with correct
    if (player_answer.equalsIgnoreCase(correct_answer)) {
        ShowToast(check_toast, "Correct", Gravity.CENTER, new Point(0, -50));

                   return true;
    } else {


        ShowToast(check_toast, "Wrong", Gravity.CENTER, new Point(0, -50));

        return false;
    }


}
```

***updated coded

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    if ((event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) || (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)) {
                        if (!b.getText().toString().equals("") && letters_in_answer < correct_answer.length()) {
                            letters_in_answer++;
                            System.out.println("letters: " + letters_in_answer);
                            int free_pos = getFirstFreeAnswerButtonPosition();
                            Button a = findButtonByPos(answer_line, free_pos);
                            a.setText(b.getText());
                            hideButton(b);
                            link_list.set(free_pos, letter_pos);
                            Helper.playSound(getApplicationContext(), "click");


                        }

                        //pops during correct answer
                            if (isCorrectAnswer()) {
                                       toUpperCase() + "!", Gravity.CENTER, new Point(0, -50));
                                Helper.playSound(getApplicationContext(), "correct");

                                //if not all images was shown we show next image
                                if (cur_image < images.length - 1) {
                                    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
                                    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom);
                                    dialog.setTitle("Title...");

                                    // set the custom dialog components - text, image and button
                                    TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text);
                                    text.setText("Android custom dialog example!");
                                    ImageView image = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.image);
                                    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                                    dialog.show();

                                    Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonOK);
                                    // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
                                    dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(View v) {
                                            dialog.dismiss();

                                        }
                                      });

                                    generateNewLevel();
                       } 

                                else {
                                    finish();

                                    Intent endgame = new Intent(GameActivity.this, EndActivity.class);
                                  startActivity(endgame);                                     
                                   finish();
                                }




             }
                        }



                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
    }
}


    }
```

Comment: if each "word" (letter?) you type it shows wrong, you call the method that validates the answer less often.

Comment: Try using method equalsIgnoreCase(String) instead of equals(Object)

Comment: @DanielBo when i click on each letter i get toast wrong.It shows even while i type right answer.i mean letters for right answer.but if answer is correct it does pass to next ques but i find problem on comparing wrong answer.

Comment: @MandarKakade i tried that but still i see toast on each letter i type

Comment: show us your code when you are calling the isCorrectAnswer() method

Comment: Are You calling isCorrectAnswer() method every time you time in a letter?

Comment: @alecnash updated code.please go through

Comment: @DanielBo  can any one help me to solve this.

Comment: I'm not shore what you're trying to do but this is how I see it: If in your quiz you input answer letter by letter then You are checking if the answer is right every time you type in one letter and that is not OK because that string (one letter that you've typed in) is not equal to answer and you get toast message. I hope that you understand what i'm trying to say :). If what I said is correct You need to check if answer is correct after user inputs the whole answer.

Comment: I suppose @majk is right.

Comment: @majk hi,what i am trying to do is i need to compare whole letter in a word and verify it with right answer.and it work when i type correct answer.but like said before problem is with wrong answer comparison.even while i type correct answer toast wrong pops up till last letter

Comment: @majk so can you give a solution referring to above code?

Comment: or @alecnash can you? i am stuck with this for days and couldn't solve

Comment: read what @majk just wrote. Your problem is logical. Just create a "submit" button and tell the user to push on it when he is done typing the answer

Comment: @alecnash actually it was coded in such a way ie when user push submit button it check answer.but i thought of making it bit different ie as soon as you fill the last block it should check for right or wrong answer .

Comment: @user3215214 how can you know when user is finished typing? If you do answer checking on every `onTouch()` event your `isCorrectAnswer()` method will be called every time

Comment: @majk so what should i do in order to achieve my idea?

Comment: @user3215214 basically You can't predict how many letters user will type in so the best bet is to have some submit button which user will click after typing or you can maybe try with something like `onFocusChange()` (but that also requires for user to click somewhere else then `EditText` field).

Comment: @majk i understand.but can you provide an alternate solution?ie consider i have images and correct answer is image name.and each empty field is generated based on length of image name.so when i fill those field the user answer must match image name if it does then given answer is correct else wrong.and i don't want to add submit button.so what should i do in order to achieve this?

Comment: so, the problem is that you validate your answer too early. Tweak you code that only words with a proper length get compared, or add something like an "Enter" button which starts the validation progress.

Comment: @DanielBo i understand my problem could be solved by adding submit button to check answer but is there any alternate solution referring to idea that i asked to majk in above comment?

Comment: @DanielBo questions loads in random so the answer length varies.

Comment: as i said, use the word length as an indicator if the solution can actually be correct. But you have to know the answer, which means you can figure out the length

Comment: @DanielBo can you help me to solve it if i send entire code.may i know your email?

Comment: sorry got no time to provide the whole solution :)

Comment: @DanielBo no problem.and thanks for your immediate response. mjak answer worked well .

Comment: @all thank you all for your immediate response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@user3215214 If user must type in all the letters than you could, in `isCorrectAnswer()` method try:

```
boolean isCorrectAnswer() {
 String player_answer = "";
    //concat all letters from answer buttons in one string
 for (int i = 0; i < answer_line.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < answer_line[i].getChildCount(); j++) {

        Button b = (Button) answer_line[i].getChildAt(j);
        player_answer += b.getText().toString();

    }
  //compare player's answer with correct
if(player_answer.length()==correct_answer.length()){
    if (player_answer.equalsIgnoreCase(correct_answer)) {
        ShowToast(check_toast, "Correct", Gravity.CENTER, new Point(0, -50));

               return true;
    } else {


        ShowToast(check_toast, "Wrong", Gravity.CENTER, new Point(0, -50));

        return false;
    }
} else return false;


}
```

Comment: @user3215214 No problems, glad I could help :)